# Refactoring "Implement Interface" using auto properties VS2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ide, refactoring, visual-studio-2015

I am trying to get Visual Studio 2015 (14.0) to use auto properties when implementing an interface using refactoring for C#.

I.e. I want this;

```
public object SomeProperty { get; set; }
```

as opposed to this;

```
public object SomeProperty
{
    get
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
    set
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

I have accomplished this in past versions of Visual Studio by editing the code snippet file (instructions [here](http://codeimpossible.com/2010/11/29/Make-Implement-Interface-use-auto-properties/)) but I cannot get this to work using Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: I also cannot do this. I have changed my propertyStub.snippet but its not registering the change. did you get this solved?

Comment: No, it looks as though there is no resolution as of yet. If I had the time I would probably make an extension for myself.

Comment: See this thread for more information https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1857694/visual-studio-2015-implement-interface-snippet-not-working

Comment: Thanks @labilbe. I think I found this a long time ago. Disappointing but hopefully there will be a workaround or implementation in the future.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, so I stumbled upon the answer during my testing of VS2019 Preview (16.0).

In the main menu bar `Tools --> Options --> Text Editor --> C# --> Advanced` look for the option `Implement Interface or Abstract Class` under `When generating properties` choose `prefer auto properties`.

This results in the same outcome that snippets used to take care of pre VS2015.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve by editing the `PropertyStub.snippet`

Just go to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC#\Snippets\1033\Refactoring` open `PropertyStub.snippet` and edit:

```
$GetterAccessibility$ get 
{ 
    $end$throw new $Exception$(); 
}
$SetterAccessibility$ set 
{ 
    throw new $Exception$(); 
}
```

to

```
$GetterAccessibility$ get;
$SetterAccessibility$ set;
```